# multi-file c++/cli .net assembly in ASP.NET web site

Tags: asp.net, c++-cli

I have a .NET assembly that I want to use in an ASP.NET web site. The assembly has the following characteristics:

- written in C++/CLI
- contains managed and unmanaged code
- compiled to x86/x64 platforms (using the correct platform-specific assembly, so it's not believed to be an issue here)
- compiled as a multi-file assembly linking several native dlls

When I try to compile I am getting an error stating:

`Could not load file or assembly '...' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

I can use the library reference without problems in an ASP.NET web application (such as MVC), but when I want to use it in an ASP.NET web site, I get this compilation issue.It seems to be something specifically related to the ASP.NET compiler.

How do I get my website to compile with this dependency?

Comment: What options are you using with the asp.net compiler? In some configurations the compilation workflow will attempt to merge DLLs, which would obviously fail with any native DLLs

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any compilation settings within Visual Studio to indicate one way or another...